# Is there an instanciable MutableList in Kotlin, avoiding java api?

Tags: kotlin

`MutableList` is an **interface**, but I cannot find a **class** in `kotlin` package that implements it explicitly. Is there any? Furthermore, I would have expected to be a package-scope defined *mutableListOf(varargs)* symetrically to *listOf(varargs)*. Up until now, I have to use java Collections.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to use `mutableListOf` or `arrayListOf`.

Comment: It would be nice if this, the accepted answer, explained this a bit more.  That `List` and `Mutable` list are a bit of Kotlin magic.  And that all Java `List` implementations are both Kotlin `List` and `MutableList` including `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` along with other custom implementations.  Kotlin has helper functions to create lists more easily as shown in this answer.  Other helpers such as `listOf` return the read only list interface `List` instead of the mutable interface.  THe ones in the answer return the `MutableLis` interface.

Comment: `linkedListOf` is gone before 1.0. There is more generic `mutableListOf` available instead.

Comment: they are only shortcuts, mutableListOf simply returns an ArrayList (which is mutable); listOf is an alternative to call Arrays.asList (which is immutable)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, java collections are the only way to get `MutableList`

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as Collections are concerned you can not avoid java API's, Because every kotlin collection uses corresponding java collection in one way or another.

***Kotlin collection interfaces are just mock interfaces***, they don't really exist at runtime. So even if you had a class implementing some kotlin collection interface(ex. `MutableList`) at runtime it would use corresponding java interface.

for example let's write two kotlin classes implementing kotlin's `List` and `MutableList` interfaces respectively

```
abstract class KotlinList : List<Int>

abstract class KotlinMutableList : MutableList<Int>
```

when you decompile these classes their signature's change as following (heads up, byte code ahead)

```
public abstract class com/example/kotlin/KotlinList implements java/util/List kotlin/jvm/internal/markers/KMappedMarker

public abstract class com/example/kotlin/KotlinMutableList implements java/util/List kotlin/jvm/internal/markers/KMutableList
```

Now both the classes implement `java.util.List` interface and they also implement  `kotlin.jvm.internal.markers.KMappedMarker` and `kotlin.jvm.internal.markers.KMutableList` interfaces respectively, so as you can see kotlin interfaces has disappeared and we are left with same old java `List` and your methods calls will now be addresses as java.util.List.someMethod and not with some kotlin interface. `KMutableList` and `KMappedMarker` as their name suggests are [marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850328/marker-interfaces-in-java) interfaces used by the  the compiler.

In case of `KotlinList` class if you look inside you will see all mutater methods of `java.util.List` are generated for you and look similar to the one below

```
   public boolean add(int var1) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Operation is not supported for read-only collection");
   }
```

So as you can see there is no way of avoiding java API's, because they are the foundation of kotlin's collections.