# How declare an interface with a type parameter that represents a type annotated

Tags: java, java-8

Having my custom annotation:

```
@Inherited
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EntityDomain {

}
```

My objective is declare an interface where the `type parameter` must be a *type* annotated with `@EntityDomain`

Such as:

```
@EntityDomain
public class Person implements Serializable {
```

I did a research in:

- [Java 8 Type Annotations](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-type-annotations)

I have created

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface EntityRetrievalForPersistence<@EntityDomain T> {

    T getEntity();

}
```

But something is missing because the following compiles:

```
public enum StringTest implements EntityRetrievalForPersistence<String>{

    A("A"),
    B("B");

    private String x;

    private StringTest(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEntity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

It should be marked how an error by the compiler because `String` is not annotated with `@EntityDomain`

What is the correct configuration?

Comment: there is no constraint for annotations, you will need to get that value using reflection and if necessary throw an exception at run time

Comment: Alternatively, you can implement your own type checker that enforces such a custom constraint, i.e. define something like `interface EntityRetrievalForPersistence<@MustBeAnnotatedWith(EntityDomain.class) T> { … }`. On the other hand, *why*? What do you gain by that, or loose by the absence of it? How does it affect code dealing with instances of `EntityRetrievalForPersistence` whether the annotation on the type parameter is present or not?

Comment: Interesting. I thought it was a valid scenario.

Comment: May i suggest another solution - why not just make `EntityDomain` a marker interface, and do: `public interface EntityRetrievalForPersistence<T extends EntityDomain>` ?

Comment: Good point, but according with the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/25850576/3665178 it for the point (3), seems better practice "How Annotations are better than Marker Interfaces?"

Comment: Annotations can be more powerful than real Java types.  However, if a regular Java type is enough to fit your needs, you should use it.  See https://checkerframework.org/manual/#faq-typequals-vs-subtypes .

Comment: Thanks to all by the replies. Feel free to post an answer to approve it how valid and close this post. Thank you.