# Pass a Lombok @Data class as parameter in a public function

Tags: java

I defined many data classes as needed for the operation, eg. `DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust`. Each data class is like below:

```
@Data
class DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust implements Serializable {
    private final String id;
    private final String advanceRequestValue;
    private final String advanceRequestShowText;

    public DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust(String id, String advanceRequestValue, String advanceRequestShowText) {
        this.id = id;
        this.advanceRequestValue = advanceRequestValue;
        this.advanceRequestShowText = advanceRequestShowText;
    }
}
```

Then in the following function`fetchDataMSDForAdvanceRequest`, I will be using this above  `DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust` in creating return values like 
`List<DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust> result = new ArrayList<>();` and somewhere else in the following code:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchDataMSDForAdvanceRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust> fetchDataMSDForAdvanceRequest(
        @RequestBody @NonNull MasterSearchRequestParam param) {

    SearchFilterForAdvanceRequestVo searchFilter = SearchFilterForAdvanceRequestVo.of(new HashMap<>());
    List<MasterSearchSimpleResult> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    tmp = availableAdvanceRequestSearchService.dbsearch(true, searchFilter);

    List<DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    String inputString = param.getInputKeyword();
    if (inputString.length() != 0) {
        for (MasterSearchSimpleResult searchR : tmp) {
            if (searchR.getShowText().contains(inputString)) {
                result.add(new DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust(Integer.toString(++count), searchR.getValue(), searchR
                        .getShowText()));
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (MasterSearchSimpleResult searchR : tmp) {
            result.add(new DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust(Integer.toString(++count), searchR.getValue(), searchR
                    .getShowText()));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I want to seperate this part of code out, as for many other fetch data function similiar to `fetchDataMSDForAdvanceRequest` above, the below part is almost identical, except the return type is different:

```
    List<DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    String inputString = param.getInputKeyword();
    if (inputString.length() != 0) {
        for (MasterSearchSimpleResult searchR : tmp) {
            if (searchR.getShowText().contains(inputString)) {
                result.add(new DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust(Integer.toString(++count), searchR.getValue(), searchR
                        .getShowText()));
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (MasterSearchSimpleResult searchR : tmp) {
            result.add(new DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust(Integer.toString(++count), searchR.getValue(), searchR
                    .getShowText()));
        }
    }
    return result;
```

I want to write a function that will takes `DataForMSDForAdvanceReqeust` as the parameter, as there are many different @Data classes available. It looks like a Generic class, but I am not sure how to carry it out if using that. I am also looking for other methods, if possible.

Do you have any idea about passing a data class as the parameter of another function?

Comment: What package is `@Data` coming from? Lombok?

Comment: @Michael you are right

Comment: In which case, the only thing common between @Data objects is that they are all objects which have various getters and setters. There is no way to use generics to constrain a class based on its annotations. Annotations are meta data. You could consider using a [marker interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850328/marker-interfaces-in-java).