# when i execute my code this error is generated java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 12.5

Tags: java, android, serialization

When I execute my code this error is generated java.lang.RuntimeException: 03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: Thu Jan 01 00:40:00 GMT+05:30 1970
03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:664)
03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:649)
03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:595)
03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:573)
03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:658)
03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:555)
03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:205)
03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:134)
03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:149)
03-22 12:40:59.735 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
03-22 12:40:59.736 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
03-22 12:40:59.736 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at in.spotrack.spolog.WebService.enterData(WebService.java:251)
03-22 12:40:59.736 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at in.spotrack.spolog.Form$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(Form.java:252)
03-22 12:40:59.736 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at in.spotrack.spolog.Form$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(Form.java:218)
03-22 12:40:59.736 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
03-22 12:40:59.736 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-22 12:40:59.737 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
03-22 12:40:59.737 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
03-22 12:40:59.737 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
03-22 12:40:59.737 2388-3294/in.spotrack.spolog W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

this class is used foe invock the webservice

```
     public class WebService {
private static String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
private static String URL ="http://www.getcodify.in/webservice.asmx";
private static String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/";


      public static  Boolean enterData(int quatity, String workdone, String 
      idelhour, String breakdownHour, String EmpId, String AssetCode,
      String OperatorName, String ConcerName, String AssetDesc, String 
      VechregNom, String ActivityCode,BigDecimal hmr_opnReading, BigDecimal 
      hmr_closingreading, BigDecimal kmr_opnReading, BigDecima 
      kmr_closingreading,BigDecimal fueIssued, String dateFrom,String 
      dateTo, String Work_closetime, String Work_starttime , String 
      webMethName)

  {

    boolean status=false;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
    //create the object for the property of the webservice method.
    PropertyInfo quatityPI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo workdonePI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo idelhourPI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo breakdownHourPI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo EmpIdPI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo AssetCodePI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo OperatorNamePI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo ConcerNamePI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo AssetDescPI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo VechregNomPI =new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo ActivityCodePI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo hmr_opnReadingPI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo hmr_closingreadingPI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo kmr_opnReadingPI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo kmr_closingreadingPI =new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo fueIssuedPI=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo dateFromPI=new PropertyInfo();

    PropertyInfo dateToPI=new PropertyInfo();

    PropertyInfo Work_closetimePI=new PropertyInfo();
     PropertyInfo Work_starttimePI=new PropertyInfo();
    //set first perameter in webservice
    quatityPI.setName("quatity");
    quatityPI.setValue(quatity);
    quatityPI.setType(Integer.class);
    request.addProperty(quatityPI);
    //Log.i("user",user);

    //set second perameter in websevice
    workdonePI.setName("workdone");
    workdonePI.setValue(workdone);
    workdonePI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(workdonePI);
    //Log.i("pass",pass);

    //set third perameter in webservice
    idelhourPI.setName("idelhour");
    idelhourPI.setValue(idelhour);
    idelhourPI.setType(Time.class);
    request.addProperty(idelhourPI);
    //Log.i("location",location);

    breakdownHourPI.setName("breakdownHour");
    breakdownHourPI.setValue(breakdownHour);
    breakdownHourPI.setType(Time.class);
    request.addProperty(breakdownHourPI);

    EmpIdPI.setName("EmpId");
    EmpIdPI.setValue(EmpId);
    EmpIdPI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(EmpIdPI);

    AssetCodePI.setName("AssetCode");
    AssetCodePI.setValue(AssetCode);
    AssetCodePI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(quatityPI);

    OperatorNamePI.setName("OperatorName");
    OperatorNamePI.setValue(OperatorName);
    OperatorNamePI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(OperatorNamePI);

    ConcerNamePI.setName("ConcerName");
    ConcerNamePI.setValue(ConcerName);
    ConcerNamePI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(ConcerNamePI);

    AssetDescPI.setName("AssetDescPI");
    AssetDescPI.setValue(AssetDesc);
    AssetDescPI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(AssetDescPI);

    VechregNomPI.setName("VechregNom");
    VechregNomPI.setValue(VechregNom);
    VechregNomPI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(VechregNomPI);

    ActivityCodePI.setName("ActivityCode");
    ActivityCodePI.setValue(ActivityCode);
    ActivityCodePI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(ActivityCodePI);

    hmr_opnReadingPI.setName("hmr_opnReading");
    hmr_opnReadingPI.setValue(new Double(String.valueOf(hmr_opnReading)));
    hmr_opnReadingPI.setType(BigDecimal.class);
    request.addProperty(hmr_opnReadingPI);

    hmr_closingreadingPI.setName("hmr_closingreading");
    hmr_closingreadingPI.setValue(hmr_closingreading);
    hmr_closingreadingPI.setType(BigDecimal.class);
    request.addProperty(hmr_closingreadingPI);

    kmr_opnReadingPI.setName("kmr_opnReading");
    kmr_opnReadingPI.setValue(kmr_opnReading);
    quatityPI.setType(BigDecimal.class);
    request.addProperty(kmr_opnReadingPI);

    kmr_closingreadingPI.setName("kmr_closingreading");
    kmr_closingreadingPI.setValue(kmr_closingreading);
    kmr_closingreadingPI.setType(BigDecimal.class);
    request.addProperty(kmr_closingreadingPI);

    fueIssuedPI.setName("fueIssued");
    fueIssuedPI.setValue(fueIssued);
    fueIssuedPI.setType(BigDecimal.class);
    request.addProperty(fueIssuedPI);

    dateFromPI.setName("dateFrom");
    dateFromPI.setValue(dateFrom);
    dateFromPI.setType(Date.class);
    request.addProperty(dateFromPI);

    dateToPI.setName("dateTo");
    dateToPI.setValue(dateTo);
    dateToPI.setType(Date.class);
    request.addProperty(dateToPI);

    Work_closetimePI.setName("Work_closetime");
    Work_closetimePI.setValue(Work_closetime);
    Work_closetimePI.setType(Time.class);
    request.addProperty(Work_closetimePI);

    Work_starttimePI.setName("Work_starttime");
    Work_starttimePI.setValue(Work_starttime);
    Work_starttimePI.setType(Time.class);
    request.addProperty(Work_starttimePI);


    //create the object of SoapSerializationEnvelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    Log.i("Envelope",soapSerializationEnvelope.toString());

    //set the weservice application language
    soapSerializationEnvelope.dotNet=true;
    soapSerializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    //create the object of HttpTransportSE and pass the url of web service in this object as a perameter.
    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    Log.i("httpTransportSE",httpTransportSE.toString());

    try{
        //invoice the web service
        httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName,soapSerializationEnvelope);
        //get the response from the webservice
        SoapPrimitive response= (SoapPrimitive) soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();
        //get the status from the web service
        status=Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());


       // Log.i("messge",loginStatus.toString());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //set the errored variable as false
        MainActivity.errored=true;
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return status;
    //return msg;
}
```

this is mainactivity.class

```
   package in.spotrack.spolog;

   import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
   import android.app.Dialog;
   import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.icu.util.Calendar;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.Build;
   import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
   import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.text.format.DateFormat;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.DatePicker;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.RadioButton;
  import android.widget.RadioGroup;
  import android.widget.TimePicker;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import java.math.BigDecimal;
  import java.sql.Time;
  import java.util.Date;

  public class Form extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText assetCodeET, assetDescriptionET, concernNameET, operatorNameET, vehicleNumberET, hmrOpenigET, hmrClosingET, kmrOpeningET,
        kmrClosingET, activityCodeET, quantityET, workDownET, employeeIdET, fuleIssuedET;

static EditText dateFromET, dateToET, startTimeET, idleHourET, closeTimeET, breakdownHoursET;

Button btn_submit;

RadioButton hmr, kmr, both;

RadioGroup radioGroup;

boolean errored = false;

Boolean displayLocation = false;

String assetCode, assetDescription, concernName, operatorName, vehicleNumber, activityCode, workDown, employeeId,
        idleHour, breakdownHours,  startTime, closeTime, dateFrom, dateTo;
BigDecimal hmrOpenig, hmrClosing, kmrOpening, kmrClosing, fuleIssued;
int quantity;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

    assetCodeET=findViewById(R.id.assetCodeId);
    assetDescriptionET=findViewById(R.id.assetDescriptionId);
    concernNameET=findViewById(R.id.concernNameId);
    operatorNameET=findViewById(R.id.operatorNameId);
    dateFromET=findViewById(R.id.dateFromId);
    dateToET=findViewById(R.id.dateToId);
    vehicleNumberET=findViewById(R.id.vehicleNumberId);
    startTimeET=findViewById(R.id.startTimeId);
    closeTimeET=findViewById(R.id.closeTimeId);
    idleHourET=findViewById(R.id.idleHourId);
    hmrOpenigET=findViewById(R.id.hmrOpenigId);
    hmrClosingET=findViewById(R.id.hmrClosingId);
    kmrOpeningET=findViewById(R.id.kmrOpeningId);
    kmrClosingET=findViewById(R.id.kmrClosingId);
    activityCodeET=findViewById(R.id.activityCodeId);
    quantityET=findViewById(R.id.quantityId);
    breakdownHoursET=findViewById(R.id.breakdownHoursId);
    workDownET=findViewById(R.id.workDownId);
    employeeIdET=findViewById(R.id.employeeIdId);
    fuleIssuedET=findViewById(R.id.fuleIssuedId);
    hmr=findViewById(R.id.hmrRId);
    kmr=findViewById(R.id.kmrRId);
    both=findViewById(R.id.bothRId);
    radioGroup=findViewById(R.id.redingtype);


    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

            if (i == 2131165250) {
                hmrOpenigET.setEnabled(true);
                hmrClosingET.setEnabled(true);
                kmrOpeningET.setEnabled(false);
                kmrClosingET.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if (i == 2131165264) {
                hmrOpenigET.setEnabled(false);
                hmrClosingET.setEnabled(false);
                kmrOpeningET.setEnabled(true);
                kmrClosingET.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if (i == 2131165221) {
                hmrOpenigET.setEnabled(true);
                hmrClosingET.setEnabled(true);
                kmrOpeningET.setEnabled(true);
                kmrClosingET.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });

    dateFromET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dateFrom(view);
        }
    });

    dateToET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dateTo(view);
        }
    });

    startTimeET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StartTime(view);
        }
    });

    closeTimeET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           ClosingTime(view);
        }
    });

    breakdownHoursET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BreakdownM(view);
        }
    });

    idleHourET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            idelM(view);
        }
    });
}

public void submit(View view) {
    if (assetCodeET.getText().length() != 0 && assetCodeET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            assetDescriptionET.getText().length() != 0 && assetDescriptionET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            concernNameET.getText().length() != 0 && concernNameET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            operatorNameET.getText().length() != 0 && operatorNameET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            dateFromET.getText().length() != 0 && dateFromET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            dateToET.getText().length() != 0 && dateToET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            vehicleNumberET.getText().length() != 0 && vehicleNumberET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            startTimeET.getText().length() != 0 && startTimeET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            closeTimeET.getText().length() != 0 && closeTimeET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            idleHourET.getText().length() != 0 && idleHourET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            activityCodeET.getText().length() != 0 && activityCodeET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            breakdownHoursET.getText().length() != 0 && breakdownHoursET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            workDownET.getText().length() != 0 && workDownET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            employeeIdET.getText().length() != 0 && employeeIdET.getText().toString() != "" ||
            fuleIssuedET.getText().length() != 0 && fuleIssuedET.getText().toString() != "")
            {
                assetCode=assetCodeET.getText().toString();
                assetDescription=assetDescriptionET.getText().toString();
                concernName=concernNameET.getText().toString();
                Log.i("concernNameET ", concernName);
                operatorName=operatorNameET.getText().toString();
                Log.i("yha tk concernNameET", operatorName);
                vehicleNumber=vehicleNumberET.getText().toString();
                Log.i("yha tk vehicleNumber", vehicleNumber);
                activityCode=activityCodeET.getText().toString();
                Log.i("yha tk activityCode", activityCode);
                hmrOpenig= BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(hmrOpenigET.getText().toString()));
                Log.i("yha tk hmrOpenig", String.valueOf(hmrOpenig));
                hmrClosing= BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(hmrClosingET.getText().toString()));
                Log.i("yha tk hmrClosing", String.valueOf(hmrClosing));
                kmrOpening= BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(kmrOpeningET.getText().toString()));
                Log.i("yha tk kmrOpening", String.valueOf(kmrOpening));
                kmrClosing= BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(kmrClosingET.getText().toString()));
                Log.i("yha tk kmrClosing", String.valueOf(kmrClosing));
                workDown=workDownET.getText().toString();
                Log.i("workDown ", workDown);
                employeeId=employeeIdET.getText().toString();
                Log.i("yha tk employeeId", employeeId);
                fuleIssued= BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(fuleIssuedET.getText().toString()));
                Log.i("yha tk fuleIssued", String.valueOf(fuleIssued));
                startTime=startTimeET.getText().toString();
                closeTime=closeTimeET.getText().toString();
                breakdownHours=breakdownHoursET.getText().toString();
                idleHour=idleHourET.getText().toString();
                dateTo=dateToET.getText().toString();
                dateFrom=dateFromET.getText().toString();
                AsyncCallWS task=new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();
            }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}





private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //disLoc.setText(displayLocation);


        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (!errored) {
            if (displayLocation) {
                Toast.makeText(Form.this, "Data is inserted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error is generated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occured in invoking webservice", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        errored = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
       displayLocation = WebService.enterData(quantity, workDown, idleHour, breakdownHours, employeeId, assetCode, operatorName, concernName,
                assetDescription, vehicleNumber, activityCode, hmrOpenig, hmrClosing, kmrOpening, kmrClosing, fuleIssued, dateFrom,
              dateTo, closeTime, startTime, "InsertData");
        return null;
    }
}

public void dateFrom(View v) {
    DateToSet newFragment = new DateToSet();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public static class DateToSet extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, day, month, year);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        dateFromET.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
    }
}

public void dateTo(View v) {
    DateFromSet newFragment = new DateFromSet();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public static class DateFromSet extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        dateToET.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
    }
}

//Class for start time


   public static class StartTimeClass extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        startTimeET.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }
}

public void StartTime(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new StartTimeClass();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}



//class clossing time

public static class ClosingTimeClass extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        closeTimeET.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }
}

public void ClosingTime(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new ClosingTimeClass();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}


//class BreakdownClass time

public static class BreakdownClass extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        breakdownHoursET.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }
}

public void BreakdownM(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new BreakdownClass();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

//class BreakdownClass time

public static class IdelClass extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        idleHourET.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }
}

public void idelM(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new IdelClass();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }
 }
```

Comment: That error indicates that you need to Serialized your model class.

Comment: how can I do...

Comment: implements Serializable ...........

Comment: not working sir

Answer (score 0):

Implement Serializable to your Model class.

```
public class WebService implements Serializable{ }
```

Comment: make sure your data types can be serializable. Here is the guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851070/java-what-can-and-what-cant-be-serialized